# MySQL syntax error #1064 - INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

Error:

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, name, url, content, category) INTO articles VALUES (null, 'Names', 'names', 'text' at line 1

PHP Code:

```
$sql = "INSERT (id, name, url, content, category) INTO articles
VALUES (null, '$name', '$url', '$content', '$category')";
$insert = MySQL_Query($sql);
```

and MySQL database table:

```
id PRIMARY  tinyint(20)     UNSIGNED   AUTO_INCREMENT 
name        varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci
url         varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci
content     longtext        utf8_general_ci
category    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, name, url, content, category) INTO articles VALUES (null, 'Names', 'names', 'text' at line 1

Comment: Field list comes after table name.See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: If those variables come from user input make sure you are escaping them, or better use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the first half of the query backwards. First you say what table to insert into, *then* you list the fields to receive values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (id, name, url, content, category)
VALUES (null, '$name', '$url', '$content', '$category')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect - it should be `insert into table_name (column list) values (value list)`. So, in your case:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (id, name, url, content, category)
VALUES (null, '$name', '$url', '$content', '$category')";
```